# Any way to remove a modifier from multiple objects in Blender?

Tags: 3d, blender, 3d-modelling, modifier, 3d-model

So, I'm doing a 5,000 frame animation for school (high school film making project, and I just want to look cool) and I just realized, while looking at the **final render**, that I have a subsurf modifier on some of my grass.

[Horrible mistake, made by yours truly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgBqC.png)

The issue is that I'm going for a lowpoly aesthetic, and this grass stands out like a sore thumb. I have somewhere in the range of 500 particles, and about 10% of them are subsurfed. It'd be great to know if there's a way to select a group of meshes and then enable/disable modifiers for all of them. Any help is appreciated :)

P.S. happy first post to me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python script, e.g.

```
import bpy
for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for m in o.modifiers:
        if(m.type == "SUBSURF"):
            o.modifiers.remove(m)
```

(use blender's builtin text editor and run script, or write/paste it directly into builtin python console)

Or instead of removing modifier you can disable its effect via e.g. `m.show_render = False`.

Comment: Thanks man! This worked wonders :) I keep forgetting that I can use Python in Blender...